Vscode : I can't use jlink (blocked on "Waiting for GDB connection..." )
I would like to upload/debug a C program for an embended MCU: cortex M0 (infineon XMC1302).
I am using windows 10, vscode and Jlink (V9). It is the first time I try to use those 2 tools together so it could be that I make a stupid mistake.
Jlink is connected to the device with SWD (2 wires + Grnd).
When I select start debugging (F5) in vscode, I get the following message
Cortex-Debug: VSCode debugger extension version 1.12.1 git(652d042). Usage info: https://github.com/Marus/cortex-debug#usage
Reading symbols from C:/Users/pc/ModusToolbox/tools_3.3/gcc/bin/arm-none-eabi-objdump.exe --syms -C -h -w C:/Data/tsdz8/mstrens_test_gpio_in_debug/GPIO_IN/build/last_config/mtb-example-xmc-gpio-toggle.elf
Reading symbols from c:/users/pc/modustoolbox/tools_3.3/gcc/bin/arm-none-eabi-nm.exe --defined-only -S -l -C -p C:/Data/tsdz8/mstrens_test_gpio_in_debug/GPIO_IN/build/last_config/mtb-example-xmc-gpio-toggle.elf
Launching GDB: Cortex-Debug: VSCode debugger extension version 1.12.1 git(652d042). Usage info: https://github.com/Marus/cortex-debug#usage
Reading symbols from C:/Users/pc/ModusToolbox/tools_3.3/gcc/bin/arm-none-eabi-objdump.exe --syms -C -h -w C:/Data/tsdz8/mstrens_test_gpio_in_debug/GPIO_IN/build/last_config/mtb-example-xmc-gpio-toggle.elf
Reading symbols from c:/users/pc/modustoolbox/tools_3.3/gcc/bin/arm-none-eabi-nm.exe --defined-only -S -l -C -p C:/Data/tsdz8/mstrens_test_gpio_in_debug/GPIO_IN/build/last_config/mtb-example-xmc-gpio-toggle.elf
Launching GDB: "C:\\Users\\pc\\ModusToolbox\\tools_3.3\\gcc\\bin\\arm-none-eabi-gdb.exe" -q --interpreter=mi2
    IMPORTANT: Set "showDevDebugOutput": "raw" in "launch.json" to see verbose GDB transactions here. Very helpful to debug issues or report problems
Launching gdb-server: JLinkGDBServerCL.exe -singlerun -nogui -if swd -port 50000 -swoport 50001 -telnetport 50002 -device XMC1302-T028x0064
    Please check TERMINAL tab (gdb-server) for output from JLinkGDBServerCL.exe
Failed to launch jlink GDB Server: Error: spawn JLinkGDBServerCL.exe ENOENT
    IMPORTANT: Set "showDevDebugOutput": "raw" in "launch.json" to see verbose GDB transactions here. Very helpful to debug issues or report problems
Launching gdb-server: JLinkGDBServerCL.exe -singlerun -nogui -if swd -port 50000 -swoport 50001 -telnetport 50002 -device XMC1302-T028x0064
    Please check TERMINAL tab (gdb-server) for output from JLinkGDBServerCL.exe
Failed to launch jlink GDB Server: Error: spawn JLinkGDBServerCL.exe ENOENT

I do not understand the message. So I also tried to run some commands in windows command prompt:
Command 1) "C:\Users\pc\ModusToolbox\tools_3.3\gcc\bin\arm-none-eabi-gdb.exe" -q --interpreter=mi2   let me get the prompt (gdb)  and asking help. So I expect that this command is accepted.
Command 2 in another windows command prompt to start jlinkgdbserver gives
C:\Program Files\SEGGER\JLink_V812>JLinkGDBServerCL.exe -singlerun -nogui -if swd -port 50000 -swoport 50001 -telnetport 50002 -device XMC1302-T028x0064
SEGGER J-Link GDB Server V8.12 Command Line Version

JLinkARM.dll V8.12 (DLL compiled Dec 18 2024 15:27:57)

Command line: -singlerun -nogui -if swd -port 50000 -swoport 50001 -telnetport 50002 -device XMC1302-T028x0064
-----GDB Server start settings-----
GDBInit file:                  none
GDB Server Listening port:     50000
SWO raw output listening port: 50001
Terminal I/O port:             50002
Accept remote connection:      localhost only
Generate logfile:              off
Verify download:               off
Init regs on start:            off
Silent mode:                   off
Single run mode:               on
Target connection timeout:     0 ms
------J-Link related settings------
J-Link Host interface:         USB
J-Link script:                 none
J-Link settings file:          none
------Target related settings------
Target device:                 XMC1302-T028x0064
Target device parameters:      none
Target interface:              SWD
Target interface speed:        4000kHz
Target endian:                 little

Connecting to J-Link...
J-Link is connected.
Firmware: J-Link V9 compiled May  7 2021 16:26:12
Hardware: V9.60
S/N: 69651235
Feature(s): RDI, GDB, FlashDL, FlashBP, JFlash
Checking target voltage...
Target voltage: 3.36 V
Listening on TCP/IP port 50000
Connecting to target...
Halting core...
Connected to target
Waiting for GDB connection...



It  is blocked with waiting for GDB connection...
I do not know how to solve this issue.
Additional notes:

Jlink is working because I was already able to flash a Hex file in the same MCU and I can read back the flash memory with jflash.exe.

Here are some Json files from vscode:

settings.json

{
    "cmake.showOptionsMovedNotification": false,
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "cmake.configureOnOpen": true,
    "[cpp]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-vscode.cpptools"
    },
    "cmake.pinnedCommands": [
        "workbench.action.tasks.configureTaskRunner",
        "workbench.action.tasks.runTask"
    ],
    "arduino.useArduinoCli": true,
    "clangd.detectExtensionConflicts": false,
    "cortex-debug.JLinkGDBServerPath.windows": "C:/Program Files/SEGGER/JLink_V812/JLinkGDBServerCL.exe", 
    "cortex-debug.JLinkGDBServerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/SEGGER/JLink_V612a/JLinkGDBServerCL.exe",
    "makefile.configureOnOpen": true
}


Extract of launch.json

"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch (JLink)",
            "type": "cortex-debug",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "executable": "build/last_config/mtb-example-xmc-gpio-toggle.elf",
            "servertype": "jlink",
            //"device": "XMC1302-T028x0064",
            "device": "XMC1302-T038x0064",
            // : "2000",
            "interface": "swd",
            "serialNumber": "",
            "preLaunchCommands": [
                // Program via the hex file to get complete coverage
                "exec-file build/last_config/mtb-example-xmc-gpio-toggle.hex"
            ],
            "overrideRestartCommands": [
                "starti"
            ],
            // svdFile is optional, it can be very large.
            "svdFile": "../mtb_shared/mtb-xmclib-cat3/release-v4.4.0/CMSIS/Infineon/SVD/XMC1300.svd",
            "breakAfterReset": true,
            "runToEntryPoint": "main",    // Specifies application entry point name where program will halt
            "preLaunchTask": "Build", // Set this to run a task from tasks.json before
                                                     // starting a debug session
            "showDevDebugOutput": "raw" 
        },
        

As explained here above, I tried

to check Jlink connection with target (and it seems OK)
to enter manually in command prompt the commands used by vscode
to run jlinkgdbserver.exe (so the gui version instead of the command line version) and It shows the result (= non connection with gdb)


It seemed that the path to jlinkgdbserver.exe was not right.
Jlink was installed in a folder named "jlink_V812" and not the default "jlink".
I had changed the path in settings.json but it did not work (even adding .exe).
Finally I created a "jlink" folder and moved all jlink files into it.
First it did not worked but I then recreated totally the project (with the default settings to "jlink" folder and it now works. I still do not understand what was wrong.

try changing the .exe file to JLinkGDBServerCL.exe.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
